# How to combine multiple indices?

Tags: combinatorics, visualization

I'm trying to combine various risk indices e.g. flooding, fire, burglary and structural damage. These values are scored from 1-3. For instance, I could have  measures for two different areas as follows:

```
    flooding | fire | burglary | structural |
            1|     2|         3|           1|
            2|     1|         1|           3|
```

My issue is that these values sum to the same score (7) despite the differences in the individual indices (flooding gets a 1 on the first row but a 2 on the second).

My end goal is to plot these values on a map. Thus, I would like a way to identify the unique combinations of each of these 4 scores. In this case I have 81 possible combinations ($3^4$).

I appreciate this is a little off topic, but I thought someone here could help.

Comment: There are different ways of doing this. You could have a weighting system. The weighting function would take each of the 81 possible results and map them to a single number. You could keep it as separate variables and map it in four dimensions (this would be far less visual, obviously). It depends a great deal on what you hope to accomplish to determine the best way to plot these values.

Comment: Well this would be a 4-D map so ... we have to think harder about what you actually want to do.  If you just want to distinguish them then just map them to the numbers $0$ to $80$.  (Map $(a,b,c,d) \to 27(a-1) + 9(b-1) + 3(c-1) + (d-1)$

Answer (score 1):

> I would like a way to identify the unique combinations of each of these 4 scores

Then map them to a four digit base 3 number.

$(a,b,c,d) \to (a-1)*3^3 + (b-1)*3^2 + (c-1)*3 + (d-1)$.

Each value gets mapped to a distinct number between $0$ and $80$.

Comment: Great, that works. The next step is to visually identify changes in these values so that it's clear when index A is increasing or index B etc.. Would it make sense to multiply each value by a colour measure?